# Running Script in Putty Server from CMD

Tags: cmd, server

There are few Database and Application servers for my application which I open through putty and run scripts in them.

I can open those servers from "Command Prompt" directly without using putty by using the following command:

`start putty.exe -ssh username@server_name -pw password`

I have put this command in a .bat file and when I run it, this will open the server.

Is there any "CMD" command which I can add in this bat file, so that it will open the server, go to the specific location and execute the given script from that location.

Thanks for your help in Advance !!

Comment: I think you need `plink`... ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/pc/network/putty/putty-0.57/htmldoc/Chapter7.html

Comment: @MarkSetchell The link is not opening for me. Can you pls provide me the correct link. Thanks.

Comment: Try Googling `plink example berlin`